# Validation Error- states that a name attribute is not allowed with Area element

Tags: validation, area

Why is a name attribute allowed with an Area element?
Here is my code that has an error.(3rd line)

Any advice is welcome as I am learning this and cannot find this in my text.

Comment: Where is you code?

Comment: I'm not sure why it is not posting. I'll put it in here. Thank you!                 <p>
     <map name="australia_map">
     <area name="South Australia" shape="rect"
      coords="305,368,495,633"
      href="australia_states.htm#South Australia"
      alt="South Australia" title="South Australia" />

Answer (score 0):

Area tag is supported below tags

```
alt
coords
download-HTML5
href
hreflang-HTML5
media-HTML5
nohref
rel
shape
target
type
```

Please refer- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

That is the reason why name attribute is throwing validation error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! The way I have the code typed in is exactly the way the text says. Is there a way to get the same effect without using the name attribute?

Comment: What you want to achieve using name attribute?

Comment: Have added a map.htm page and are breaking it up into sections(areas) and then when the mouse is hovering over an area it will state what area it is on ie: South Australia.